# What does self destruct in a contract mean?

Tags: fantom

When I see https://ftmscan.com/address/0xe32e98b79329c045c72613b717a4cd0c168c3c49

There is a writing that the contract is self destruct. What does it mean?

Some says that no one knows the private key of the contract. So how does a contract be told to send money to another?

This is an address that is involved in a limit order contract from spooky swap.

It seems that the gelato contract send money to this address and then the address self destruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self destruct allows a contract and its storage to be deleted from the blockchain (subsequent blocks).

self destruct takes one argument, where to send the contract's funds to before self
destructing

contracts have to have logic/functions written for the purpose of moving funds. If you deploy a contract without a function to get funds out ... you won't be getting any out of it ... unless you're able to self-destruct the contract

Comment: so the purpose is to save some gas. Also if the contract is marked as gone then some software can read that and say no limit order

Comment: Yeah. I'm not familiar with the contract so I don't know, but you do get a bit of a refund from releasing the storage and it would be possible to detect that there is no contract/code at that address anymore